# Nvidia dedicated graphics slower than Intel integrated

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, nvidia-prime

I have a laptop with Geforce 640M video and Intel i5-3317U processor(Acer Aspire M3-581TG).

Nvidia uses driver 331.113 and Intel integrated graphics uses i915. With Nvidia Prime, when I switch to Nvidia card, my performance is a lot worse than it is with Intel across various games.

When I use this command that I saw in another thread:

`lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA`

both GPUs say they are the VGA controller, maybe that is causing some conflict?

How can I get the proper performance out of Nvidia Card?

Comment: Ubuntu never seems to work well with NVIDIA. Why not just stick with the Intel?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Then what would be the point of having that GPU at all?

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work... No, I'll try to help. Where did you install the driver from?

Comment: It was there under additional drivers, says from nvidia-331 (proprietary, tested). Not sure from which ppa.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: Yeah I've rebooted many times since I first got it.

Comment: Try reinstalling it from the terminal. The Additional Drivers page will tell you the package name.

Comment: Done, no noticeable difference in performance. Intel still better.

Comment: How much video RAM does the card have?

Comment: 1GB on Nvidia GPU

Comment: Maybe update to 14.10?

Comment: That will take some time it seems. I'll comment again when it's done, thanks for the fast replies.

Comment: I too have had inconsistent results with nvidia proprietary drivers, such that at one point I had to "downgrade" to the last one to work properly.  Higher revision numbers are not always better.

Comment: I've had terrible issues when upgrading to 14.10. Got stuck at blank screen, unable to boot. I will try a fresh install from USB later. Anything else I can try on 14.04?

Comment: "Donwgraded" from 331.113 to 304.125.  Installed 304.125 using from nvidia-current. In the additional drivers menu it says thats a legacy driver. Prime wouldn't work with it so I removed prime and installed Bumblebee. So far everything seems to be in order, should I post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using legacy drivers worked.

I was trying different things and noticed

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

installs Nvidia 304.125 and not 331.113 drivers. So I did the install.

After that, I was unable to switch graphics with Nvidia Prime. So I removed it

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove nvidia-prime
```

and installed Bumblebee instead, as described here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

Note: I restarted my pc after each step just to be safe.

Now my GPU behaves as expected.

It had terribly low performance and was heating up a lot using 331.113 drivers, I guess something is wrong with those, even though it says tested under additional drives window.